# How to track different button clicks with Google Analytics and AJAX?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, google-analytics

I have several pages, let's call them A, B and C.
Each of these pages has a form where the user can type in some information and click a button to send those information to the server. This button click is performed in an UpdatePanel to prevent a full postback.

A customer of ours now wants to know how many % of the using visiting each site (A, B and C have different URLs) use this form.  (Meaning I need seperate values for A, B and C)
How to I track this in Google Analytics? It seems that I have to create a conversion(??) for each page. Is that correct?

How must I modify the existing web application to let Google Analytics know, that a user submitted the form. (without the need to redirect thank to xy amount of different thank you pages)

The only piece of information I've found so far is this: http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55519
Unfortunately, this FAQ entry does not cover my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A project i have released allows for easy integration with Google Analytics to fire page views and events through native .net code.

This way you can simply call a method that will log either and event or a page view for you. You can do this in your web service's code.

It's called GaDotNet and can be found here: http://www.diaryofaninja.com/projects/details/ga-dot-net

This library really just is a wrapper for sending requests to the Google tracking pixel (example url below).

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.6.5&utmn=488134812&utmhn=facebook.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1024x576&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-gb&utmje=0&utmfl=10.0%20r42&utmdt=Facebook%20Contact%20Us&utmhid=700048481&utmr=-&utmp=%2Fwebdigi%2Fcontact&utmac=UA-3659733-5&utmcc=__utma%3D155417661.474914265.1263033522.1265456497.1265464692.6%3B%2B__utmz%3D155417661.1263033522.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B
```

Comment: There's a fair bit to it in terms of generating session tokens etc. You can take a loot at exact code here: https://github.com/dougrathbone/Ga.net/blob/master/GaDotNet.Common/Data/TrackingRequest.cs

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `pageTracker._trackPageview` with a unique string when the button is clicked using Javascript.

For more precise instructions, please provide more detail.

Comment: Where do I get this unique string? Must I register it in Google Analytics? How can I track conversion rates with it? Like Site A 20% conversion, Site B 5% Conversion, Site C 70% Converison